# Longtable doesn't stay within the page borders

Tags: tables, longtable, width

This is the code I have used

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\linespread{1.2}

\begin{longtable}{@{}llllll@{}}
\caption{}
\label{Table 2}\\
Regression 1B: & & & 
\\
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{6}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\endhead
%
\multicolumn{6}{l}{2012 reform} \\* \midrule

Logit estimates                                              & Model 1 & Model 2  & Model 3  & Model 4                   & Model 5                   \\* \midrule
Entry year      & -.091***      & -.077***      & -.063***                      & -.102***                  & -.064***                  \\
                                                             & (0.000) & (0.000)  & (0.001)  & (0.003)                   & (0.002)                   \\
Female                                                       &         & .883***  & .833***  & .798***                   & .833***                   \\
                                                             &         & (0.000)  & (0.000)  & (0.000)                   & (0.000)                   \\
BAME                                                         &         & -.700*** & -.618*** & -.618***                  & -.620                     \\
                                                             &         & (0.000)  & (0.000)  & (0.000)                   & (0.000)                   \\
Female x entry year                            &         &          &          & \checkmark &                           \\
BAME x entry year                              &         &          &          &                           & \checkmark \\* \midrule
Controls                      &               &               & \checkmark     & \checkmark & \checkmark \\* \midrule
Observations                                                 & 165,280 & 165,280  & 165,280  & 165,280                   & 165,282                   \\
Reported coefficients; p-values in parentheses               &         &          &          &                           &                           \\
*** p\textless{}0.01, ** p\textless{}0.05, * p\textless{}0.1 &         &          &          &                           &                          
\end{longtable}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

How do I make the table stay within the page borders. As it currently goes off to the right and also overlaps the page number at the bottom too

Comment: Why do you use longtable for such a short table? It could easily fit onto a single page.

Comment: Regarding the width issue, \multicolumn{6}{l}{Reported coefficients; p-values in parentheses} should help in order to reduce the width of the currently overly wide first column.

Comment: @leandriis great thank you!

Comment: A random remark --- I'd suggest using `$\times$` rather `x` for the interaction terms, that'll give you a proper multiplication sign and look better. Also, using `$-$` rather than just `-` for the negative coefficients will give you a proper minus sign rather than a dash. And finally, you might want `$p < 0.01$` etc.

Comment: @chsk really useful thank you

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is to create a `\multicolumn` of the last two rows.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\linespread{1.2}    

\begin{document}    

\begin{longtable}{@{}llllll@{}}
    \caption{}
    \label{Table 2}\\
    Regression 1B: & & & 
    \\
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{6}{c}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
    \endhead
    %
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{2012 reform} \\* \midrule
    
    Logit estimates                                              & Model 1 & Model 2  & Model 3  & Model 4                   & Model 5                   \\* \midrule
    Entry year      & -.091***      & -.077***      & -.063***                      & -.102***                  & -.064***                  \\
    & (0.000) & (0.000)  & (0.001)  & (0.003)                   & (0.002)                   \\
    Female                                                       &         & .883***  & .833***  & .798***                   & .833***                   \\
    &         & (0.000)  & (0.000)  & (0.000)                   & (0.000)                   \\
    BAME                                                         &         & -.700*** & -.618*** & -.618***                  & -.620                     \\
    &         & (0.000)  & (0.000)  & (0.000)                   & (0.000)                   \\
    Female x entry year                            &         &          &          & \checkmark &                           \\
    BAME x entry year                              &         &          &          &                           & \checkmark \\* \midrule
    Controls                      &               &               & \checkmark     & \checkmark & \checkmark \\* \midrule
    Observations                                                 & 165,280 & 165,280  & 165,280  & 165,280                   & 165,282                   \\ \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{Reported coefficients; p-values in parentheses}                   \\
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{ *** p\textless{}0.01, ** p\textless{}0.05, * p\textless{}0.1} 
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Are you really need `longtable`? From code fragment can be concluded that no, so instead of long table you can use for example `tabularx` and for notes below table use `tablenotes` determined by `\threeparttablex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{dingbat}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{X}{#2}}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{table-space-text-pre={(},
         table-align-text-pre=false,
         table-space-text-post={***},
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-format=-1.3
         }
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{My long table}
    \label{Table 2}                                             
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{5}{S} @{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{6}{@{} l}{2012 reform}                                 \\* 
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{} l}{Regression 1B:}                              \\
Logit estimates
    & \mcx{Model 1} & \mcx{Model 2} & \mcx{Model 3} & \mcx{Model 4} & \mcx{Model 5} \\* 
    \midrule
Entry year      
    & -.091***  & -.077***  & -.063***  & -.102***  & -.064***  \\
    & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.001)   & (0.003)   & (0.002)   \\
Female                                                       
    &           & .883***   & .833***   & .798***   & .833***   \\
    &           & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   \\
BAME                                                         
    &           & -.700***  & -.618***  & -.618***  & -.620     \\
    &           & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   \\
Female x entry year                            
    &           &           &           &\checkmark &           \\
BAME x entry year                              
    &           &           &           &           &\checkmark \\* 
    \midrule
Controls                      
    &           &           &\checkmark & \checkmark &\checkmark \\* 
    \midrule
Observations                                                 
    & {165,280} & {165,280} & {165,280} & {165,280} & {165,282} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
\note{
Reported coefficients; $p$-values in parentheses:
\item[***]  $p<0.01$,
\item[**]   $p<0.05$,
\item[*]    $p<0.1$
     }
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

- If you for some unknown reason persist to brake your table between pages, than I would consider to use `xltabular` and `threeparttablex` packages. Also for better align of numbers I would employ `siunitx` package and for `\checkmark` use fonts `dingbat`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{dingbat}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{C}{#2}}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

    \begingroup
\sisetup{table-space-text-pre={(},
         table-align-text-pre=false,
         table-space-text-post={***},
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-format=-1.3
         }
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
\note{Reported coefficients; $p$-values in parentheses:
\item[***]  $p<0.01$,
\item[**]   $p<0.05$,
\item[*]    $p<0.1$
     } 
    \end{TableNotes}
%
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{5}{S} @{}}
\caption{My long table}
    \label{Table 2}                             \\
    \toprule
    Regression 1B: & & &                        \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{ continued from previous page}   \\
\endhead
%\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
% table body
\multicolumn{6}{@{} l}{2012 reform}                                 \\* 
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{} l}{Regression 1B:}                              \\
Logit estimates
    & \mcx{Model 1} & \mcx{Model 2} & \mcx{Model 3} & \mcx{Model 4} & \mcx{Model 5} \\* 
    \midrule
Entry year      
    & -.091***  & -.077***  & -.063***  & -.102***  & -.064***  \\
    & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.001)   & (0.003)   & (0.002)   \\
Female                                                       
    &           & .883***   & .833***   & .798***   & .833***   \\
    &           & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   \\
BAME                                                         
    &           & -.700***  & -.618***  & -.618***  & -.620     \\
    &           & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   \\
Female x entry year                            
    &           &           &           &\checkmark &           \\
BAME x entry year                              
    &           &           &           &           &\checkmark \\* 
    \midrule
Controls                      
    &           &           &\checkmark & \checkmark &\checkmark \\* 
    \midrule
Observations                                                 
    & {165,280} & {165,280} & {165,280} & {165,280} & {165,282} \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{ThreePartTable}
    \endgroup
    
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)